# How to show $G=G_m+G_n$ where $G$ is a finite abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ a finite (additive) abelian group of order $|G|=mn$ and such that $gcd(m, n)=1$. Suppose $$G_m=\{g\in G: o(g)\mid m\}\quad \textrm{and}\quad G_n=\{g\in G: o(g)\mid n\}$$ How can I show $$G=G_m+G_n=\{g+h: g\in G_m, h\in G_n\}?$$

**Obs:**

**(i)** I have already shown both $G_m$ and $G_n$ are subgroups and $G_m\cap G_n=\{0\}$.

**(ii)** Maybe the hypothesis $G$ is abelian won't be needed. Later I'll try to show $G\simeq G_m\times G_n$ so that hypothesis will fit here, I guess..

Thanks.

Comment: $G_m\cap G_n$ is not true, unless you add the condition that $m,n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notation $o(g)∣m$: does this mean $g^m = 1 \vee \forall i<m : g^i \neq 1$ ?

Comment: @pqnet That means the order of $g$ in $G$ divides $m$.

Comment: How do you treat a case like $m=n=2$ and the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_4,+$ (the cyclic group of order 4)? It is certain that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \neq  \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ (Klein's "Vierergruppe").

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so it is just the first of the two condition I wrote, $g^m = 1$ right?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, this is an additive group so this should be something like $g\times m = 0$

Comment: Yes, that's another way of putting it, @pqnet.

Answer (score 2):

We'll consider any group, not just Abelian groups.

Assuming $(m,n)=1$,  there is $x,y$ so that $mx+ny=1$. Then any element $g\in G$ can be written as $g=g^{mx}g^{ny}$. Since $o(g)\mid mn$, we see that $g^{mx}\in G_n$ and $g^{ny}\in G_m$, so $g\in G_n\times G_m$.

When $G$ is not abelian, $G_n$ and $G_m$ are not necessarily subgroups.

When $m,n$ are not relatively prime, we can quickly find an example: $G=(\mathbb Z_{12},+)$ with $m=6$ and $n=2$. Then $G_m=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ and $G_n=\{0,6\}$. So $G_m+G_n=G_m\neq G$

Comment: Let $g\in G_m\cap G_n$. Since $o(g)\mid mn$ we have $o(g)\mid m$ and $o(g)\mid n$, right? So $o(g)$ would be a commom divisor of $m$ and $n$ hence $o(g)=1$ so that $G_m\cap G_n=\{0\}$ and I didn't use $G$ is abelian, is something wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: That doesn't prove that $G_n$ and $G_m$ are subgroups, only that they have only one element in common. Consider $S_3$ with $m=2$ and $n=3$. There are three elements of order $2$ in $S_3$, and they completely generated $S_3$. @PtF

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about my observation $(i)$.. I agree..

Comment: My comment about (i) was that this wasn't true unless $m,n$ relatively prime, before you added that to the question. @PtF